# Sum up Values from Sharepoint List column

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have 4 columns with choice field type. Each column has 1,2,3,4,5 value . Now if I select value from each column and submit it should add up those number. If some other user login and do the same thing it will add up the numbers with the previous user's total. Incase user changes the value then it should not add up with the existing one whereas it should add up only the changes.

I need some logic/code to achieve this using JSOM

Comment: How are these numbers added (custom JavaScript on form, sandbox event receiver etc.?). If you are using JavaScript, then how do you fetch values, from item or from UI controls?
And where is the sum put?

Comment: I will be using JavaScript to fetch item based on its selection. Like I have choice column which are radio button so user can select only one value , based upon the selection I will add each column's value to get the final one.

Comment: Can anyone please give some ideas to accomplish the same...

Comment: Your requirement and solution are still not clear to me. It will be great if you can provide more details and write it step by step and also which step is not working as expected.